# How to give border radius react-bootstrap dropdowns

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using React-bootstrap dropdowns, here is the code :

```
<DropdownButton id="dropdown-Nav" variant="danger"> 
    <Dropdown.Item as="button">object1</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item as="button">object2</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item as="button">object3</Dropdown.Item>
</DropdownButton>
```

But I'm getting square dropdowns instead of rounded ones.
[image]

How can i give `border-radius` to my dropdowns.

Thnaks in advance

Comment: why not do css styling on it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css.

```
#dropdown-Nav {
   border-radius: 5px;
}

#dropdown-Nav .dropdown-menu {
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: The OP wants rounded borders, why `border-radius: 0`?

Comment: Sorry. let me fix it.